# Python virtualenvwrapper: 'workon' hangs indefinitely

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Title more or less says it all. Attempting to `workon $SOME_VIRTUALENV` echoes the command, then hangs indefinitely at high CPU (~70%) until it's `kill -9`'d. On OS X Mavericks.

I've searched around, and most similar problems seem to be from people using zsh (which I'm not) and are also getting crashes on tab-completing virtualenv names (which I'm not), so I'm somewhat at a loss. Not much to go on, I know, but I'm not exactly a bash expert, and even some suggestions on how to get some real diagnostic information would be appreciated.

```
$ echo $OSTYPE
darwin13.1.0

$ echo $SHELL
usr/local/bin/bash

$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.0.0(1)-release

$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

$ python --version
Python 2.7.8

$ pip show virtualenv
---
Name: virtualenv
Version: 1.11.6
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:

$ pip show virtualenvwrapper
---
Name: virtualenvwrapper
Version: 4.3.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: virtualenv, virtualenv-clone, stevedore
```

.bashrc (more or less copy-pasted from somewhere):

```
# Locate virtualenvwrapper binary
if [ -f /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh ]; then
    export VENVWRAP=/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
fi

if [ ! -z $VENVWRAP ]; then
    # virtualenvwrapper -------------------------------------------
    # make sure env directory exists; else create it
    [ -d $HOME/sites/env ] || mkdir -p $HOME/sites/env
    export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/sites/env
    source $VENVWRAP

    # virtualenv --------------------------------------------------
    export VIRTUALENV_USE_DISTRIBUTE=true

    # pip ---------------------------------------------------------
    export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
    export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false
    export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true
    export PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=$HOME/.pip/cache
fi
```

Comment: What happens if you create a brand-new virtualenv: `mkvirtualenv test -p /usr/local/bin/python`. Does `workon test` still hang?

Comment: Later, you can remove the `test` virtualenv with: `rmvirtualenv test`.

Comment: Also, if you run `set -x`, then bash will show you all the commands being executed. That *might* help locate where `workon XYZ` is hanging. Later, you can turn off the verbose mode with `set +x`.

Comment: A new virtualenv worked fine -- should obviously have tried that, sorry. Deleting and recreating the one I was working on and copying the source folder back into it also worked. However, once I reinstalled the project requirements, it hangs again. The only output with `set -x` was

    `+ workon $blah
    + in_args=("$@")`

There's a fair number of requirements; guess I'll go through myself and see if I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: Consider opening an issue on the [bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/)?

Comment: Try `bash -x /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh $SOME_VIRTUALENV` to see where it hangs specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, for any poor souls searching this later:

I did eventually find the culprit for this problem, if not the reason. The custom tab completion set up by virtualenvwrapper was causing a major problem somehow; if I tried to tab-complete a `workon` command, the next command entered would cause the problem described above. This occurred even if I Ctrl-C'd out of the tab-completed command and entered a brand new one.

So, I just stopped using tab-completion on `workon`, and removed the content of the function `virtualenvwrapper_setup_tab_completion` (replacing with a do-nothing `true`) in `virtualenvwrapper.sh` to ensure I couldn't do it accidentally.

I could probably dive deeper and figure out *why* the tab-completion would cause the problem, but it's just not worth the effort right now. There were a couple other examples of people having issues with virtualenvwrapper's tab completion that I found, but in those instances the terminal just immediately crashed when they tried to use it, which is not what happened here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure what you're putting in your bashrc, don't put it there. Maybe the paths are doing weird things and that is the reason everything getting stuck.

Please try to comment the thing written there.

Follow the steps from here: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html or run:
locate virtualenvwrapper.sh

The path that you get is something you need. edit you .bashrc and add:
source /path-of-what-you-got-earlier/virtualenvwrapper.sh

After the change save and close and do:
source .bashrc

(maybe you'll need to configure WORKON_HOME anyway. I don't remember) Try to see if anything changed.

If not, try to create new virtualenv